# What does $R \rightarrow R$ means in functions?

Tags: functions, notation, real-numbers

I have a function.

The function is:

$$ f:R \rightarrow R $$
$$ f(x) = x^3$$

What does $R \rightarrow R$ means?

I don't know what types of questions should I ask here. If it is not ok, the I will delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that its domain and co-domain are real numbers. Do not confuse co-domain with range/image. The range of a function is indeed a subset of co-domain which consists of all of outputs of the function.
.

Answer (score 8):

Intuitively, it means that for every $x \in R$, the function f will give back a value $f(x) \in R$.

For example, a function $f(x)=1/x$ is only defined for those $x \in R$ Real Numbers $R$ that are different from $0$, so you should write $f: R/\{ 0 \} \rightarrow R$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually a function is a subset of a product $A\times B$ that has the property that for every $a\in A$ there exists exactly one $b\in B$ such that pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ belongs to it. Then $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$ wich means the same as $f(a)=b$.

In that context the notation $f:A\rightarrow B$ is used. The set $A$ is by definition the domain of the function and the set $B$ is the codomain. It is also called "range" instead of codomain, but often authors make a distinction between range and codomain and the range is then defined as $\{b\in B\mid\exists a\in A [b=f(a)]\}$ wich is a subset of $B$.