# Does $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean that $f(x)$ is defined for all real inputs?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ basically means that the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of $f$ is the set of real numbers and the range of $f$ is the set of real numbers. However, does it mean that $f(x)$ is defined for all $x\in R$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166570/768162) might help you in answering the question.

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: Also, the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ not necessarily the range.

Comment: yes, the notation means the function is defined on all of $\mathbb R.$ However, it doesn’t mean the range is $\mathbb R.$ The range is some unknown subset of $\mathbb R.$ The set on the right of the arrow is usually called to “co-domain.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the definition of a function $f$ encapsulates instructions for, given each input from $f$'s domain, which particular output from $f$'s codomain (in fact, from $f$'s range) to return.